# async await obtain exception from inner task result

Tags: c#, async-await

Given the following snippet:

```
public Task StartReading()
{
  var activityCheck = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await this.CheckActivityTimeout(), this._token.Token).Unwrap();
  var reading = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await this.ReadAsync(), this._token.Token).Unwrap();

  // for reference, this code produces the same result:
  // var activityCheck = this.CheckActivityTimeout();
  // var reading = this.ReadAsync();

  return Task.WhenAny(reading, activityCheck);
}
```

When an exception is thrown in `CheckActivityTimeout`, I am catching it as follows.

```
var read = StartReading()
var tasks = new Task[] { read, taskx, tasky, taskz };
int completed = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
var r = tasks[completed];
```

`r` does not have it's exception set. Instead, if I look at the debugger, I find that the task `r` has the exception stored within a `Result` property. How do I get to this actual result?

`r` has type ``` Id = 17, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise``1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult]" ```

You can see that the actual exception is inside the result of the *inner* task. How do I propogate it upwards?

`r.Exception == null`
`r.Result` is inaccessible.

**update**

```
var r = Task.WhenAny(tasks).Result; // produces exactly the same wrapped result!
```

In the debugger it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but `Task.Factory.StartNew` does not support `async` delegates. Use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: Also, any reason why you are creating a new Task to call the async methods like `CheckActivityTimeout`? why not calling them directly?

Comment: Changing the code to use `Task.Run` has the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is because of how `Task.WhenAny` works. `Task.WhenAny` returns a task *whose result is the task that completed*. This is why `read.Result` is a task, which in turn contains the exception.

It's not really clear what the *desired* semantics are, but if you want `StartReading` to surface the result of the first completed task, you can use a "double await", like this:

```
public async Task StartReadingAsync()
{
  var activityCheck = this.CheckActivityTimeout();
  var reading = this.ReadAsync();
  await await Task.WhenAny(reading, activityCheck);
}
```

On a side note, don't use `StartNew`. If you have CPU-bound (or other blocking code) that you need to move off the UI thread, then use `Task.Run`; otherwise, just call the methods directly.

Comment: So `await await Task.WhenAny(reading, activityCheck);` is the up voted answer, hmm? I would have thought there should only be one `await` -- like my answer calls out.

Comment: @DavidPine: `await await` observes the inner task exception. That is, the inner `await` gets whichever task completed first (this `await` never fails); then the outer `await` observes the results of that task, propagating any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I learned something today... It is kind of ugly though.

Comment: @DavidPine: Yeah, it's a tossup. You can alternatively do `await Task.WhenAny(...).Unwrap();` which some people prefer. Either way, this is a rare use case.

Comment: Since you could chain `.Unwrap`, could you also have `await await await await ...`, that could chain as well?

Comment: @DavidPine: Yes. But I'd first look at refactoring the code. :)  Two `await`s is rare, multiple would be *very* odd. Though perfectly legal from a language standpoint. "`await`" is just like a unary operator - it can participate in any expression, including other expressions with `await`.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that another solution to the problem is just to cast the result to `Task<Task>`

Casting the result of `Task.WhenAny` will also obtain the inner task.

```
 var result = Task.WhenAny(reading, activityCheck).Result;
var inner = ((Task<Task>)result).Result;
inner.Exception...
```

Comment: stack overflow should not allow downvotes without a comment, this works just fine.